# What is going wrong with the class defination in expressjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have added a response class in expressjs as follows

```
module.exports = function(req,res) {
  this.req = req;
  this.res = res;
  console.log(this.res);

  this.ok = function() {
    this.res.status(200).end();
  }

  this.err = function(err) {
    console.log(this.res);
    this.res.status(400).json({err:err.message});
  }
};
```

And i am calling it using

```
route.post("/",function(req,res){
  var authCtx = new authHelper(req,res);
  var respCtx = new response(req,res);
  authCtx.checkForm()
    .then(respCtx.ok)
    .catch(respCtx.err);
});
```

The problem is when i create an object of class the first `console.log` prints the complete response fine without any errors but in second case when error is invoked the `this.res` becomes empty. Where am i going wrong with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little research i found out that the correct way to define class would have been

```
module.exports = function(req,res) {
  this.req = req;
  this.res = res;
  console.log(this.res);

  this.ok = () => {
    this.res.status(200).end();
  }

  this.err = (err) => {
    console.log(this.res);
    this.res.status(400).json({err:err.message});
  }
};
```

Comment: The (arguably more) correct way would to call the methods properly bound `.then(respCtx.ok.bind(respCtx))`. The expected behavior in JS actually is that `this` is not fixed to a particular object instance in a function.

Comment: @Tomalak your solution is definately better, had to use `that` inside promise to get access to current object instance :)

Comment: arrow function works as, it does not bind to its own this. other way is to write: `const that =this;` and use that every where.

Comment: Using a closure variable for the self-reference (I normally call it `self`) is the other common way to do it. Generally I am not sure whether your `Response` object design is a smart move to begin with. It adds complexity while not really making anything a lot easier in your router.

Comment: @Tomalak the thing is api design is dynamic and loaded from database so had to make this class to make stuff simpler and maintainable. I did the same thing you are saying with `self` for reference inside promise :)